# Location reload crashes webpack dev server - Vue 2

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack

I'm using Vue-CLI tool, in my main component App.vue:

```
// template code omitted for convenience
@Component
export default class App extends Vue {
  private mounted(): void {
    // checking app version
    const storage = window.localStorage

    this.$http.getVersion().then((resp: any) => {
      const version = resp.data.id

      if (storage.getItem('app_version') !== null && storage.getItem('app_version') != version) {
        window.location.reload(true)
        storage.setItem('app_version', version)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Logic behind this code, is to refresh a browser on a client-side, when i re-deploy my web-application to a server. Without this thing, user has to manually refresh a browser in order to see a changes, it's inconvenient for users.

`this.$http` - is an axios instance;

`resp.data.id` - returns version as number;

The problem here, is when i manually change a version in a `localStorage` (in a browser), then refresh the browser, my webpack dev-server is crashing with an error:

"serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1"

Also checked full debug log:

```
11 silly lifecycle project@0.1.0~serve: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle project@0.1.0~serve: Failed to exec serve script
13 verbose stack Error: branchio@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/alexanderkim/.nvm/versions/node/v12.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:326:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:209:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/alexanderkim/.nvm/versions/node/v12.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:209:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
```

What might be this?

Comment: maybe put  `storage.setItem('app_version', version)` before the reload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intention of this reloads was to purge the browser cache, after app re-deployment.

I fixed it with nginx cache busting:

```
location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate';
    expires 0;
}
```

Vue-CLI 3 be default is hashing all assets, so it was index.html responsible for this.